# Android What is Preference.getExtras() used for?

Tags: android, android-intent, preference, extras

The Preference class has a method called getExtras().
It may or may be not related to the Preference intent, but the Extras can be get and put using the intent directly.
There is no method putExtra/s() in the Preference class, then...
what is the purpose of getExtras()? In which scenrarios is it used?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> what is the purpose of getExtras()?

It doesn't really do anything useful. Seriously.

In [the `Preference` source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.2_r1/android/preference/Preference.java), there is a `private` member variable `mExtras`:

```
private Bundle mExtras;
```

However, it's never changed in any way (and cannot be accessed by outside classes whatsoever), except in the following:

```
public Bundle getExtras() {
    if (mExtras == null) {
        mExtras = new Bundle();
    }
    return mExtras;
}
public Bundle peekExtras() {
    return mExtras;
}
```

I suppose it might be used for something in the future, but it was added in API 11 and remains useless through API 16.

> There is no method putExtra/s() in the Preference class, then... In which scenrarios is it used?

I guess you could use it for associating items with a preference, like:

```
Bundle extras = myPref.getExtras();
extras.putString("KEY", "Value");
```

You don't need `putExtra()` to do so, instead accessing the `Bundle` directly. But that's about all it's useful for, it seems.

Answer (score 1):

It's not explained all that well in the documentation, but `#getExtras` is meant for preferences that start another fragment through `#setFragment`. Any extras specified on the preference [are passed to the specified fragment](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.java#1433), so long as you're using `PreferenceActivity`.

Comment: For anyone else who stumbles upon this- The way to fetch this extra on the other side from the target fragment:
`getArguments().getString(YOUR_KEY);`

Answer (score 0):

To improve the topic. The `getExtras()` is particularly useful for associating some data with preferences that are generated dynamically, for example a list of switch preferences. Then you attach the `Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener#onPreferenceChange(Preference,Object)` and listen to them all. Once the state of preferences changes, you get their extras directly. Otherwise you had to maintain a `HashMap` of preference keys for their corresponding payload data.